# How can I get a stable Eclipse + Java 7

Tags: java, eclipse

Finally, after centuries of discussion and development, Java 7 is released! It doesn't really help me though, because I find it very hard to get a somewhat stable version of Eclipse which supports its new language features.

According to http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_7_Support_%28BETA%29 I need to get a maintenance release of Eclipse. However, the version mentioned (M20110729-1400) I can't find anywhere, and [this page](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/eclipse3x.php) doesn't mention any maintenance releases.

I also tried "Check for updates" in my existing 3.7 Eclipse but that just returns some updates for some plugins.

Where can I get a workable version of Eclipse that supports Java 7?

---

(I'm not desperate for Java 7, and won't switch to another IDE for it)

(I tried Eclipse 3.8 M1, but that's such an early version, it even still has Indigo on the splash screen.)

(I love Eclipse, but their site/monster network needs some usability testing)

Comment: Try netbeans, it fully supports Java 7 since version 7.0.

Comment: @Mahmoud I used to use NetBeans regularly. Telling someone to drop one tool for another has a huge productivity impact. Yes, they are very similar in terms of capability, but it's not that easy to just get up, drop a tool set, and switch to another one.

Comment: @Thomas I know it's not that easy, I was just proposing a temporary solution, that's all.

Comment: Questions about programming tools are off-topic here and should go to [SO].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there isn't a stable Eclipse that supports Java 7...yet. It is slated for a 3.7.1 update (Indigo SR1). I haven't looked, but a milestone or nightly for Indigo SR1 would probably be more stable than a 3.8 milestone or nightly release. Unfortunatly, the [download page](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/eclipse3x.php) doesn't appear to have a 3.7.1 build, unless the 3.7.x Stream Builds are for 3.7.1 (I'm not familiar enough with Eclipse's release strategy to know for sure).

EDIT: As of now, there are [stable builds of 3.7.1](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/eclipse3x.php) (thanks for Jason S for pointing this out). I have not tested it with Java 7 to confirm that everything works as expected, since I'm still targeting Java 6 at work and in my personal projects and have yet to upgrade.

Comment: I looked up SR1 and found that RC2 should be out for it right now. Unfortunately, that's unfindable either.

Comment: 3.7.x stream builds are for the next 3.7 maintenance release. The current builds (M201108xx) are for 3.7.1. After releasing 3.7.1 the next 3.7.x stream builds will go for 3.7.2.

Comment: @Csaba_H: So today's build is the RC2 that should be out today, not some broken nightly?

Comment: @Bart: according to the 3.7.1 endgame plan (http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/plans/freeze_plan_3_7_1.php) the M20110824-0800 should be the RC2 build. It should be stable enough.

Comment: It's out now, apparently! (Sep 9 build)  http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/eclipse3x.php

Comment: @JasonS It looks like it's supposed to be out, but the build for 3.7.1 failed.

Comment: The link posted was messed up, but it's been fixed. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=358688

Answer (score 1):

I've found Eclipse 3.8 M1, Netbeans 7.0.1 and IntelliJ 10.5 to all work fine for me.  Netbeans is probably my favourite to work with for Java 7 (their hints to help you convert code to Java 7 idioms are great).